# Select part of line in regular expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

[I have this string](https://regex101.com/r/7Er0Ch/2):

```
#1#http://test.ir:8080/srvSC.svc#1#
#2#http://test.ir:8081/srvSC.svc#2#
#3#http://test.ir:8082/srvSC.svc#3#
#4#http://test.ir:8083/srvSC.svc#4#
#5#http://test.ir:8084/srvSC.svc#5#
#6#http://test.ir:8085/srvSC.svc#6#
```

I want to select all `#1# #2# ...` so in order to i wrote this expression : `^(^\#.\#)` but it just select first line.How could i select first `#.#` and last of `#.#`?

Comment: Remove your two start-of-line anchors and it works as expected. No need for that capture group either, since it'll be the same as the whole match. You also don't need to escape `#`s.

Comment: Thanks dude. https://regex101.com/r/7Er0Ch/3 why last line is not selected? @CertainPerformance

Comment: Because `#.#` matches only one character between the `#`s. Did you want `#\d+#`?

Comment: That's it.But now if i want select all word except `#\d#` what can i do ?@CertainPerformance

Comment: Is that what your actual question was trying to ask? Eg you want to match `http://test.ir:8080/srvSC.svc`, `http://test.ir:8081/srvSC.svc`, and so on?

Comment: yes @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(#\d+#)(.+)\1$
```

That will capture the first `#`s in a group, repeat any characters, and then match the same characters that were matched in the first group. The string you want will be in the second captured group.

https://regex101.com/r/7Er0Ch/5